# List of sites like the old LiveMocha

Tags: discussion

If anyone knows of any site that's similar to the old LiveMocha (not the abomination Rosetta Stone turned it into), I'd be interested to hear about them.  On the old LiveMocha one could search the site for people who spoke a particular language (and what their proficiency level was), and you could talk to them live if they were online, either via text chat or via voice.  I really miss this community aspect with most language learning sites - it's just boring lessons.  Once you get OK at a language, you want to talk to people not just take lessons.

---

Est-ce que quelqu'un connaîtrait des sites similaires à l'ancien LiveMocha (pas l'abomination que Rosetta Stone a fait), je serais intéressé d'en connaître d'autres.  Sur l'ancien LiveMocha on pouvait rechercher sur le site des personnes parlant un langage en particulier (et quel était leur niveau de compétence), et on pouvait parler avec eux s'ils étaient en ligne, soit par tchat écrit, soit en laissant des messages vocaux. Cet aspect communautaire me manque beaucoup dans  la plupart de sites d’apprentissage des langues - C'est seulement des leçons ennuyeuses.  Une fois qu'on devient bon dans une langue, on désire parler avec des personnes, pas juste prendre des leçons.

Comment: Pas entièrement ce que tu cherches mais peut-être à essayer : http://polyglotclub.com/

Answer (score 2):

J'étais très présente aussi sur le site Livemocha aussi, avant son rachat et sa destruction complète par Rosetta, qui a ainsi "flingué" un concurrent.

Il n'y a pas d'équivalent à ce qu'était Livemocha, mais dans un autre style, très agréable et sociable, je peux te conseiller [Duolingo](http://www.duolingo.com). C'est celui qui se rapproche le plus au niveau de la sociabilité et du fait d'avoir des leçons interractives.

**PS**: J'ai corrigé quelques erreurs dans ton texte, je te le signale pour ça puisse t'aider.